# Execute package utility outside Visual studio Error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I was trying to run a dtsx file outside Visual studio and got the erro

> " To run a SSIS package outside of data tools you must install Sscript task of integration service or higher"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install this packet

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Usually the problem is this, you don't have installed the correct Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Business Intelligence.